# Jade template not using bootstrap css correctly

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express

I am using Express to create a website. However, my jade template is not displaying the bootstrap grid system correctly. I have made sure that my app path is set right through app.use(express.static(path_join... but the problem still exists. My layout.jade:

```
doctype
html( lang="en" )
  head
    title Edward's Photo Album
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
body
  block content
```

and here is my cats.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  -for(var x=1; x<=imagenum-1; x++)
    .row
      .col-md-4
        h2 hello world
```

It displays hello world vertically instead of horizontally. https://gyazo.com/968198ce7016a06d9bc7964a18a6d848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you loop, you seem to be creating a new ".row" div. Rows are horizontal. Inside of each row you are created a new column with the "hello world" inside of it.

Why not create the row outside of the loop so there is only one row.

```
.row
  -for(var x=1; x<=imagenum-1; x++)
    .col-md-4
      h2 hello world
```